# What exactly happened to Luke Cage in that experiment after which he got his powers?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, marvel-cinematic-universe, luke-cage

In the episode of *Marvel's Luke Cage* the process of him getting his extraordinary strength and powers isn't really explained well. He is immersed in an electrical setup involving a certain mixture of chemical solutions. The experiment's levels go beyond the permissible/expected ones and he gets the extraordinary strength through the chemical reaction his body goes through. Wikipedia also explains this in brief:

> Burstein immerses Lucas in an electrical field conducted by an organic chemical compound; when he leaves Lucas unattended, Rackham alters the experiment's controls, hoping to maim or kill Lucas. Lucas' treatment is accelerated past its intended limits, inducing body-wide enhancements that give him superhuman strength and durability.

But what exactly happened to Luke's body? What alterations took place in his body externally and internally? (Organs, cells, skin etc.) I am looking for a detailed answer.

Comment: He gets a tiara of power.

Answer (score 2):

The Netflix shows don't go into scientific detail about the specifics of Luke or anyone else's powers at this time. The wider Marvel Cinematic Universe also glosses over many superhuman powers. For example,  Cap is injected with a Super Soldier Formula that "brings out what's in side a man". Very technical.

So what we fall back on is the source material. In the comics, Luke's power comes from his regenerative process increasing the density of his muscle and skin cells. He's nigh invulnerable from most attacks because of how tough his skin is. Without any negative side effects of denser cells. But if you pierce his skin, his internal organs are normal strength. Again, avoiding the realities of squishy organs in a solid body, inertia, his strength, etc.

Comment: I dont think he internal organs are normal strength, they say all his tissues are now in ultra density layers.

Comment: @marcio you mean his comic second power up? That also gave him his power man invulnerable jacket? Or in show?

Comment: his internal organs are normal. as you can see in the episode where they try to do the experiment on him again  and with a syringe can get blood from the inside part of his neck